# Creating database in sdcard

Tags: android, database, sd-card

Is it possible to create the database in sdcard. If possible please tell m some tutorials.
I know how to create database locally.
I am searching in internet, but I am  not getting proper tutorials.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory)` will create a database in any folder you like (and have permission to write in).

Barry

Comment: Hi, I have tried this one, but it gives exception "Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file"

Comment: You need permission to write to the SD card. Add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> to your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

This might help out.

http://www.anddev.org/creating_database_on_sdcard_-t7817.html

Take a look at all the responses, especially the third oneThe method of interest is `SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbFile, null);`

Comment: Hi, I have tried this one, but it gives exception "Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file"